# Python instance to COM Object

Tags: python, com, ole

I'm having a bit of a play with using COM objects with Python and have run into a small problem.

The COM object I am using has a method called `SetCallback` which takes a `object`, the mothod looks like this:

```
    [id(0x60010010)]
    void SetCallback([in] IDispatch* callbackobject);
```

*Taken from MS OLE/COM Object viewer*

Now if I create and instance of my COM app in python everything is fine until I try and pass an instance of a object to this method.

```
callback = Callback()
mycomobject.SetCallback(callback)

class Callback():
    def SetStatusText(self,status):
        print status
```

The error I get in the python window is: `TypeError: The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object`

When doing the same thing in C# I used to make my class def look like this:

```
[ComVisible(True)]
public class Callback 
{
   //some methods here
}
```

and the method call is the same as Python version.

**Is there something like this I have to do in Python in order to use an instance of a  object as a callback for a COM object.**

Comment: interesting problem.  The com system works great with standard python datatypes (int, strings, unicode...).  Would it be possible to create a workaround, like make a monitoring class that could mimick the SetCallback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out! Just needed to make my own COM server and register it, then create the object via Dispatch:

```
class Callback():
    _public_methods_ = ['SetStatusText']
    _reg_progid_ = "mycomobject.PythonCallback"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{14EF8D30-8B00-4B14-8891-36B8EF6D51FD}"
    def SetStatusText(self,status):
        print status

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Registering COM server..."
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Callback)
    main()
```

in main()

```
callback = Dispatch("mycomobject.PythonCallback")
#callback.SetStatusText("Hello World")
mycomobject.SetCallback(callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the object will need to be COM compliant.
I wouldn't know out of the box to be honest, but we have a somewhat similar situation (in a software from a vendor) that is addressed on their end by using ActiveState's ActivePython.

Works alright both ways, with a dispatcher to automatically wrap COM compliant objects for python access, and the other way around.
If you don't have licensing and/or financial constraints it might be worth giving it a look.

Looking forward to the replies if someone can crack it open without any additional libraries.